# Python turtle color changing and fill

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This code draws a shape when the user inputs the number of squares to draw and the size of those squares. I want the color to change for every square that is drawn, and for it to get filled in.  But the code gets stuck:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

size = int(input("How long do you want the side lengths to be?"))
number = int(input("How many squares do you want in the image?"))
red = 40.0
blue = 30.0
green = 10.0

def square (size):
 count = 0
 while count < 4:
  t.forward(size)
  t.right(90)
  count = count + 1

def drawing(number):
  times = 0
  while times < number:
    t.pencolor(red, blue, green)
    t.fillcolor(red, blue, green)
    t.begin_fill()
    square(size)
    t.right(360/number)
    if t.filling():
      t.pensize(5)
    else:
      t.pensize(3)
    t.color()
    (red + 1, blue + 1, green + 1)
    times = times + 1

drawing(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code -- the primary one is you're using the wrong color model.  By default, turtle colors are specified as floating point values between 0.0 and 1.0.  However, you want to use values like those in your code, we can switch this via `colormode(255)` which allows values from 0 to 255.

Next, a `begin_fill()` has to have a matching `end_fill()` which you are missing.  Colors are specified in the order `(red, green, blue)`, not `(red, blue, green)`.  Also, if you set both `pencolor()` and `fillcolor()` to the same color, you can simply use the one call `color()`.

Finally, these two statements don't do anything:

```
t.color()
(red + 1, blue + 1, green + 1)
```

as far as your code is concerned.  You need to rethink them.  Below is my rework of your code which addresses the above issues and some other details:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def square(size):
    count = 0

    if turtle.filling():
        turtle.pensize(5)
    else:
        turtle.pensize(3)

    while count < 4:
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(90)
        count += 1

def drawing(number):
    red = 30
    green = 10
    blue = 20

    times = 0

    while times < number:
        turtle.color(red % 255, green % 255, blue % 255)

        turtle.begin_fill()
        square(size)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.right(360 / number)

        red, green, blue = red + 20, green + 30, blue + 10
        times += 1

size = int(input("How long do you want the side lengths to be? "))
number = int(input("How many squares do you want in the image? "))

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

drawing(number)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]